# Как сделать анализ данных на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, анализ-данных

У меня есть два массива в которых хранятся данные следующего формата:

1. `[5, 6, 7, 4]`
2. `[13:54/04.01.2023, 14:20/04.01.2023, 15:20/04.01.2023, 16:54/04.01.2023]`
   (Это примеры списков, на самом деле они постоянно дополняются)

На основе этих данных будут видны зависимости пиков данных от времени или даты года, мне нужно, что бы какими-либо библиотеками анализировать и предугадывать примерные значения.
Как это сделать?

Comment: _"Как это сделать?"_ очень просто - изучить одну из подходящих библиотек (например scikit-learn, CatBoost и т.п.), создать модель, обучить ее на тренировочных данных, протестировать на тестовых данных, при необходимости подправить параметры модели и повторить обучение, следить чтобы модель не переобучилась, получить предсказание, визуализировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте книги по анализу временнЫх рядов - там есть ответы на ваши вопросы.  "Анализировать и предугадывать" вообще, вне конкретики -  невозможно. Есть задачи, на которые распадаются любые задачи по исследованию временных рядов. И из которых собираются решения в зависимости от задачи и ваших данных. Главная из них - построение модели временнОго ряда. Модели тоже бывают разные. От элементарных скользящих средних, экспоненциального сглаживания, Хольта-Винтерса, SARIMA до GARCH, нейросетей RNN и LSTM и их модификаций.   В экосистеме Python для всего этого используются модули -  scipy (с кучей своих подмодулей), statsmodel.tsa, tensorflow, scikit-learn, естественно щедро приправленное возможностями из numpy и pandas .
А есть еще специализированные пакеты Facebook Prophet, экзотические pycaret, tsfresh, darts  или заточенный на поиск "пиков" (аномалий) PyOD и пр.
Книжек по этому вопросу - горы. И отдельно по анализу рядов и даже в контексте использования Python. Что на русском, что на английском. Из первого, что попалось под руку:

```
Маккинли У. Python и анализ данных
Atwan T.A. Time Series Analysis with Python Cookbook
Lazzeri F. Machine Learning for Time Series Forecasting with Python
```

или в сильно упрощенном и адаптированном для новичков виде:

```
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/07/time-series-forecasting-complete-tutorial-part-1/
https://habr.com/ru/company/ods/blog/327242/
```

Изучить это все по подсказкам на этом сайте - точно не удастся. По сути - это целый очень большой раздел машинного обучения и статистики. Но если в ходе чтения указанных источников возникнут конкретные вопросы -  задавайте, попробуем ответить. (Не забудьте при этом правильный тег вопроса задавать "временные ряды", а не все подряд).